# 'Commands out of sync' in MySQL caller-function

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to clean up my PHP, in particular the MySQL SP calls. I would like to be able to execute my stored procedures by a simple function call like:

```
    $result = run_procedure("sp_test(2)");
```

I have tried a number of aproaches, but every time I run into the *Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now* - error when execuring the function more than once.
Here's one of my attempts. See how I even copy the content of the resultset into an array and frees the resultset before returning the array? Why do I still get the error?

```
function run_procedure($procedure_string) {
   open_connection(); // A seperate func that opens the global $db_connection;

   $procedure_result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["db_connection"], "CALL " . $procedure_string,MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);
   if (mysqli_errno($GLOBALS["db_connection"])) {
      die("Query fail: " . mysqli_error($GLOBALS["db_connection"]));
   }
   $result_array = array();
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($procedure_result)) {
      $result_array[] = $row;
   }
   mysqli_free_result($procedure_result);
   return $result_array;
}
```

I would acually prefer just to return the resultset (and not build the array here), but I can't make that world either.

Any good ideas? Anyone using a seperate function for MySQLi execution as well?

Comment: Does the procedure return more than one result set from an unbounded `SELECT`?  I'm not a PHP specialist but perhaps http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.more-results.php is needed to fetch more data and clear the handle?

Comment: There's only one select in the procedures. But anyway, the same thing happens if I don't call SP's but simply execute SQL with this same method...